# 400 Bad request for ASP .NET Web API filestream characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, file, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I have a file upload API running in IIS. I am calling it from a WPF Application. I have file names like "Test-12345–Coverage–TestFile-2018Jul23".

If you see this file name, it has got a '-' and a '–'. Eventhough they look alike, they are different. Our clients get these filenames generated through some external system, but when I try to upload these files through my webapi. I am getting a 400 Bad request error. It looks like '–' is treated as an invalid character in the http request making it a bad request. If I change '–' to a '-', it works fine.

**Is there a list of restricted characters in http request stream objects?** If so I would like to know and share it with my clients. There is a debate of application should handle these characters since windows file system allows naming files with these characters. But if IIS rejects it, I don't know what to do. Please advice.

```
Stream s = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\Desktop\Test**-** NoticeInfo **–** funding- July 26, 2018.pdf");

StreamContent content = new StreamContent(stream, Convert.ToInt32(buffer));

_httpClient.PostAsync("http://myurl/api/v1/UploadDocument", content); //The code breaks here
```

Notice the '-' in the file name. There are two occurences. First one is a standard Keyboard '-'. The second one is a different hyphen. These file names are generated from another system and we are using it to upload in our system. But for some reason IIS did not like the second –, it treats the whole request as a bad request.

Comment: can you provide you code for the upload? It looks like a simple upload code doesn't show the same behavior.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Please find the code